# Completion suggester not returning all suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, nosql

I'm using  completion suggester for auto completion. Everything is fine. but I'm not getting all   matched suggestions. I'm getting below 10 suggestions. How to increase suggestions count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the "size" attribute in the search request.

Look at the documentation at
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Example:

```
POST music/_search
{
    "_source": "suggest", 
    "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "nir",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest", 
                "size" : 20 
            }
        }
    }
}
```